# Memory leak in rails app..creating log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

We've been dealing with a memory leak issue with our Rails app. We're using Ruby 2.5 and We're suspecting that it has to do with symbols not being garbage collectible. I'd like to implement a file where I log the symbols size (Symbol.all_symbols.size) during the life of the application. It should be updated after every request (after_action inside ApplicationController). I'm not sure how to implement this and what the file should look like. I could use some help.

Comment: Hi, Please take a look at this gem https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks , it will help you understand whats going on with the app. Also, welcome to StackOverflow :) Can you also share more details about how did you realize that symbols are not garbage collected and it is the reason for memory leak in your application?

Comment: @Abhinay is correct, you might want to start with a profiler to locate the actual problem points before going down this rabbit hole.

Comment: @Abhinay@max We're actually not sure what's causing the memory leak and what objects are living in the memory and not being closed. We're suspecting symbols.